# SQL Server Word Frequency for Each ID

Tags: sql-server, word-frequency

I have a SQL Server table with an ID and a text column with size of ~ 15,000 words. For each ID, I want to return a list of every unique word and the number of times it occurred.

```
CREATE TABLE MyComments (
Textid char(20) NOT NULL,
Comments VARCHAR(MAX)
)

Answer would look like
    TextID  Word     WordCount
    ------- ------   ----------
    1        cost     5
    1        expense  7
    2        cost     12
    2        revenue  11
 

..
```

Comment: Are you sure you want SQL Server to do this? More than once?

Comment: To get `a list of every unique word` you can use the function STRING_AGG. TO get `the number of times it occurred` you can use the function COUNT(DISTINCT Word) and finally Group the result by `id`. Note! Please provide your attempt to use this approach if you do not succeed and need more help and in addition please provide sample data by posting query to INSERT some sample rows

Comment: by the way, You should add the tag `tsql` to the question. This is pure tsql question `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really something SQL Server is designed to do; it will be extremely expensive to do this for a table that is large (large number of rows, extremely long text like 15K, or both). If your table is small:

```
SELECT c.Textid, Word = s.value, WordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.MyComments AS c
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.Comments, ' ') AS s
  GROUP BY c.Textid, s.value
  ORDER BY Textid;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b82577562cf532629ef0a193e432358d)

At scale, this query will be terrible.

As [@lptr pointed out](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e4203c326b2acafbe8b249ec85685375), likely better at large scale to rearrange this query in a more complicated way so that the splitting is separated from the rest of the logic:

```
SELECT c.Textid, Word = s.value, s.WordCount
  FROM dbo.MyComments AS c
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT value = CONVERT(varchar(255), value),
           WordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(c.Comments, ' ')
      WHERE LEN(value) > 0
      GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(255), value)
  ) AS s
  ORDER BY c.textid;
```

But this is still pretty slow (for an 8,000-row table it did almost 600,000 reads and took ~15 seconds). I don't believe SQL Server is the place to do this work.

Comment: Spot-on solution, however, I suspect OP has failed to consider punctuation and CRLFs.   i.e. dog vs dog, vs dog. and dog.{CRLF}

Comment: ..it might be better to cross apply ( split group by) instead of aggregating all split values of all rows

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Probably right, it's why I suggested SQL Server isn't the right place to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The fact it is slow isn’t a problem.  A different part of the project took 36 hours to run. The data comes from the SEC and we have limited options to solve the problem. 

This solution worked beautifully.